# MVC Core and EF Core data grouping with Linq or something that can produce the desired result

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a SQL query that return the result to List

```
public class WebTrafficStat
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Stat { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSubTotal { get; set; }
}
```

The result must be displayed as HTML Pivot table with either results grouped by "Stat" or "Group" field.

SQL result:

[image]

Desired result as HTML

[image]

I did the functions that does this PHP but now the project must be written in MVC Core

This is my PHP functions that I used currently

I grouped the array from SQL call results here:

```
function array_group_by(array $arr, $gElement, $gkey) {

$refined = $arr;
$result = array();      

foreach ($arr[$gElement] as $data) {
  $id = $data[$gkey];

  if ( isset($data[$gkey]) && !empty($data[$gkey]) ) {

      if (isset($result[$id])) {
         $result[$id][] = $data;
      } else {
         $result[$id] = array($data);
      }   
  }   
}

if ( !empty($result) ) {
  $refined[$gElement] = array();

  foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
    $refined[$gElement][] = array('name' => $key, 'childs' => $value);
  }

  $refined['grouped'] = 1; 
}
```

return $refined;
}

And second function is

```
function grouped_array_to_html ($grouped, $groupField ){

$tableRows = array();
$columns = array();
$Row_Data = array();    

if ( $grouped['grouped'] == 1 ){ // grouping found

    $columns[] = 'Group';

    // table columns/headers
    foreach ($grouped['rows'] as $row) {

        foreach ($row['childs'] as $child) {

            if ( !in_array($child[$groupField], $columns ) ){

                $columns[] = $child[$groupField];
            }       
        }   
    }

    //table rows

    foreach ($grouped['rows'] as $a => $row) {      

        $tableRows[$a][] = $row['name'];    

        foreach ($row['childs'] as $c => $child) {      

            foreach ($columns as $x => $col){

                if ( $col == $child[$groupField] )
                {
                    $tableRows[$a][$x] = $child['total'];
                    break;
                }                   
            }                   
        }   
    }   

    //Output Finale 

    foreach ( $tableRows as $b => $tr )
    {

        foreach ($columns as $c => $col) {

            if ( !isset($tableRows[$b][$c]) )
                $Row_Data[$b][$c] = '-';
            else    
                $Row_Data[$b][$c] = $tableRows[$b][$c];             
        }   
    }

} else { // no grouping


    foreach ($grouped['rows'] as $row) {        
        $Row_Data[] = $row;     
    }

}

$htmlOut = array(
    'theaders' => $columns,
    'trows' => $Row_Data
);

$grouped['rows']['html'] = $htmlOut;

return $grouped;
```

}

And I call PHP like this ... this gives me HTML table header rows and Body rows
In this case, I tell it to group by "Stat" column

```
$result = grouped_array_to_html( array_group_by($response, 'rows', 'group'), 'stat' );
```

So please how can I achieve same result using EF Core or Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up approaching it like this:

```
    if ((Model.WebReport != null) && Model.WebReport.Rows.Any())
{

    var columns = Model.WebReport.Rows
        .Select(c => (Model.GroupBy.Equals("Group") ? c.Stat : c.Group))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    columns.Insert(0, "Group");

    var reportStat = Model.WebReport.Rows
        .GroupBy(g => (Model.GroupBy.Equals("Group") ? g.Group : g.Stat))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Group = x.Key,
            Stats = x.ToDictionary(y => (Model.GroupBy.Equals("Group") ? y.Stat : y.Group), y => y.Total)
        });

    Model.Columns = columns;
    Model.ReportStats = reportStat.ToList();
}
```